# Auto submit form in yii2 when onkeyup a filed

Tags: yii2, rating-system

I using yii star rating for restaurant system, i have 'rating' table with field 'value' for save rate from user. When user click the star, form will submit without click button Send?

[image: Image Demo]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to trigger the click on submit button, or fire submit event on the form when the user clicked on the star.

```
$(document).on('click', 'yourStarItemSelector', function() {
    $('yourFormSelector').submit(); 
    // or $('submitttButtonSelector').trigger('click');
})
```

If u use activeForm:

```
$(document).on('change.yii',"inputWithStarSelector", function(){
           $('yourFormSelector').submit(); 
           // or $('submitttButtonSelector').trigger('click');
});
```